# Reverse lookup in django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models as follows

`class IntakeDetails(models.Model):
    intake = models.ForeignKey(intake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecturer = models.ForeignKey(Lecturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    module= models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

`class AssignAssignment(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    duedate=models.DateField()
    intakedetails=models.OneToOneField(IntakeDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='details'`

I have a queryset

```
queryset = IntakeDetails.objects.filter(lecturer=self.request.user.id)
```

it filters all the intakedetails that belong to that lecturer in that table. but i want it to filter that intakedetails that doesnt exist in assign assignment model.
anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following based on the related_name `details`:

```
IntakeDetails.objects.filter(lecturer=lecturer_id,details__isnull=True)
```